# The account associated with this portal has no owner

Tags: community

I am setting up community user.
As suggested, I got an existing account ID (I used my own account, which is an admin account) and pasted it into my SiteRegisterController, so it looks like this:

```
public with sharing class SiteRegisterController
{   
     private static Id PORTAL_ACCOUNT_ID = '00590000000aB8l';﻿ // ID of my newly created account

     // snip ...
}
```

But after I fill in all the details and hit siubmit on the self-registration page at /SiteRegister, I get:﻿

Errors

Your request cannot be processed at this time. The site administrator has been alerted.
The account associated with this portal has no owner

I have a role set up too. Any help would be grately appreciated

Comment: Your question has already an answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789883/customer-portal-self-registration-error-the-account-associated-with-this-porta

Comment: I Changed the account id to "001K0000015M5FD". Still I am facing the same error

Comment: do you need to enable self registration?

Comment: This issue is related to the user that is creating the community user. So if you're creating the user, make sure you have a ROLE associated with your user id.